# Remove namespace and namespace prefix of element

Tags: xslt

**Dear Experts, I have Input request with SOAP Env, from that  which need to be capture only body of  by using XSLT
And at the same time, need to remove namespace on the element and also name space prefix of every element.**

**Input Request**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:v1="http://xmldefs. ag.com/Applications/eer/V1">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<v1:ProcessDistr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <v1:Group xmlns:ns2="http://xmldefs.ag.com/DD/Commons">
    <v1:GroupID>437848</v1: GroupID>
    <v1:Status>true</v1:Status>
    <v1:Parent>45434554</v1:Parent>
  </v1:Group>
</v1:ProcessDistr>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Output Received**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <v1:ProcessDistr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmldefs. ag.com/Applications/eer/V1">
      <v1:Group xmlns:ns2="http://xmldefs.ag.com/DD/Commons">
        <v1:GroupID>437848</v1: GroupID>
        <v1:Status>true</v1:Status>
        <v1:Parent>45434554</v1:Parent>
      </v1:Group>
    </v1:ProcessDistr>
```

**XSLT code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:v1="http://xmldefs. ag.com/Applications/eer/V1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsltc="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/xsltc" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" xmlns:prof="http://ixult.net/ProfileExchange" exclude-result-prefixes ="v1" xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
       <!-- Output -->
       <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


       <xsl:template match="/">
          <!-- filter ProcessDistr-->

             <xsl:copy-of select="//v1:ProcessDistr"/>

       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I am expecting this output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessDistr >
  <Group >
    <GroupID>437848</GroupID>
    <Status>true</Status>
    <Parent>45434554</Parent>
  </Group>
</ProcessDistr>
```

Could you please share me your view on this.

Thank you very much.

With Best Regards,
Sateesh N

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:v1="http://xmldefs. ag.com/Applications/eer/V1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://xmldefs.ag.com/DD/Commons"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs SOAP-ENV wsu v1 ns2 xsi"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="SOAP-ENV:Envelope">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SOAP-ENV:Body/v1:ProcessDistr"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v1:ProcessDistr">
        <xsl:element name="ProcessDistr">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v1:Group">
        <xsl:element name="Group">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v1:GroupID">
        <xsl:element name="GroupID">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v1:Status">
        <xsl:element name="Status">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="v1:Parent">
        <xsl:element name="Parent">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
Try this
```

Comment: Why not simply `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`?

Comment: Hello Michael, Can you please elaborate me about your logic simple way?

Answer (score 0):

The result you want can be achieved simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:v1="http://xmldefs.ag.com/Applications/eer/V1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="v1:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo** (after removing the superfluous spaces from your input): https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqc